# Javascript. Remove node based on children value

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say I have this html.

```
<tr>
      <td>Spain</td>
      <td>Madrid</td>
      <td>Barcelona</td>
      <td>Sevilla</td>
</tr>

<tr>
      <td>UK</td>
      <td>Scotland</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
</tr>
```

And now I would like to remove a `tr` whose children `td` values are Spain, Madrid and Barcelona, no matter what the 4th children has.

How to carry this out¿? If with jQuery, would be even better.

Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$("tr:contains('Spain'):contains('Madrid'):contains('Barcelona')").remove();
```

also make sure you've wrapped your `tr`s within a `table` in your markup

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that takes 2 parameters: your table element, and the values to match, in an array. You could call it like this:

```
filterOut(document.getElementById('myTable'), ['Spain', 'Madrid', 'Barcelona']);
```

#### Demo

```js
function filterOut(table,contents){
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
      cells,
      match;
  for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
    match = true;
    cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var j=0, l=cells.length; j<l && j<contents.length; j++){
      if(cells[j].textContent.trim() != contents[j]) { match = false; break; }
    }
    if(match){ rows[i].parentNode.removeChild(rows[i]); i--; }
  }
}

document.getElementById('filter-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  filterOut(document.getElementById('myTable'), ['Spain', 'Madrid', 'Barcelona']);
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Spain</td>
    <td>Madrid</td>
    <td>Barcelona</td>
    <td>Sevilla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>Scotland</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Spain</td>
    <td>Madrid</td>
    <td>Barcelona</td>
    <td>London</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Spain</td>
    <td>Madrid</td>
    <td>Paris</td>
    <td>Sevilla</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="filter-btn">Filter</button>
```